# How to view ACPI RTC alarms?

Tags: windows-7, acpi

My PC resumes at 8:30 when it's in standby mode, and I would like to check if there is an RTC alarm that causes it. How can I view currently set alarms in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking Windows 7's Task Scheduler in Control Panel.  There might be a scheduled task in there waking up your computer.  Also, check your power management settings in your BIOS in case a manual RTC alarm has been set.

> To Run Task Scheduler using the
>   Windows interface
>
> 1. Click the Start button.
> 2. Click Control Panel.
> 3. Click System and Maintenance.
> 4. Click Administrative Tools.
> 5. Double-click Task Scheduler.